# Changing variable inside $interval through angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to build something like an alert on the screen.I am now using angular.js and some OOP to do that.This is the code.

main is an instance which I created inside in the ng controller.

```
$scope.main = new ran_num();
```

html part

```
<p>{{ main.count }}</p>
```

js part(The actual code is kind of too long, so I just pick the part I have problems with).

```
var self = this;
if(self.player[self.player.length-1] != self.ran[self.player.length-1]){
      self.player = [];
      self.mode = "computer";
      var l = self.count;
      self.count = "Wrong";
      a = $interval(function(){
        console.log(self.count);
        console.log("wrong");
        if(self.count == 'Wrong')self.count = '- -';
        if(self.count == '- -')self.count= 'Wrong';
      },400,4);
      self.count = l;
       var c = setTimeout(function(){
          self.play_all_sound("computer");
      },500);
      self.mode = "human";
    }
```

What I want to do is when the first if statement is fulfilled, the main.count should toggle between "Wrong" and "- -",which looks like a warning.When I console log the self.count inside the interval,I found it shows undefined,I am not sure which part of the code goes wrong?

Comment: `this` is controller instance. It can be specified with controllerAs syntax. It can't be 'created' with `$scope.main = new ran_num()`

Comment: Sorry I am really new to this,should I say object?